# SQL Query different Max values with date

Tags: php, sql, database, sqlite

My table

```
ID | sensornode | temperature | humidity | pressure | voltage | datetime
 1           Node1       27.81       23.78        1029.7      3.321       2017-04-20 14:17:24
 2           Node1       27.93       23.72        1029.7      3.321     2017-04-20 14:17:39
 3           Node1       28.1        23.68        1029.8      3.321    2017-04-20 14:17:54
 4           Node1       28.08       23.62        1029.7      3.321     2017-04-20 14:18:09
 5           Node1       28.21       23.58        1029.8      3.321    2017-04-20 14:18:24
 6           Node1       28.37       23.54        1029.7      3.321     2017-04-20 14:18:39
```

I needed to select the Max & Min values of  temperature, humidity and pressure. This is the PHP-method to select the max and min

```
public function getMaxMin($nodeId, $datetimestart, $datetimeend){
        $values = array(
            ':nodeId'        => $nodeId,
            ':datetimestart' => $datetimestart, 
            ':datetimeend'   => $datetimeend
        );

    $sqlmax = "SELECT 
        MAX(temperature) as temperature,
        MAX(humidity) as humidity,
        MAX(pressure) as pressure
        FROM measurement
        WHERE nodeId =:nodeId
        AND datetime BETWEEN :datetimestart 
        AND :datetimeend"; 

    $sqlmin = "SELECT 
        MIN(temperature) as temperature,
        MIN(humidity) as humidity,
        MIN(pressure) as pressure
        FROM measurement
        WHERE nodeId =:nodeId
        AND datetime BETWEEN :datetimestart 
        AND :datetimeend"; 

    $max = $this->queryDatabase($sqlmax, $values);
    $min = $this->queryDatabase($sqlmin, $values);
    $data = array('max' => $max[0],
                  'min' => $min[0]
    );
    return data;
```

It worked well, but now I need to select the depending 'datetime' of each min and max value. Of course, I could query the database for each Max and Min value, but it would not be a pretty solution. Is there a possibilty to do this with two querys?

**Edit:**
The current output of both querys are stored in the data-array

```
$data = Array
(
    [max] => Array
        (
            [temperature] => 29.56
            [humidity] => 74.23
            [pressure] => 1029.02
        ) 
    [min] => Array
        (
            [temperature] => 7.61
            [humidity] => 19.27
            [pressure] => 1019.28
        )

)
```

But I'm searching for this:

```
$data = Array
    (
        [max] => Array
            (
                [temperature] => 29.56
                [t_datetime] => 
                [humidity] => 74.23
                [h_datetime] =>
                [pressure] => 1029.02
                [p_datetime] =>
            ) 
        [min] => Array
            (
                [temperature] => 7.61
                [t_datetime] =>
                [humidity] => 19.27
                [h_datetime] =>
                [pressure] => 1019.28
                [p_datetime] =>
            )
)
```

Comment: Can you show us  desired output from your table?

Comment: Please show us your expected output.  Note that the result set may not be as clean as your current one, because the maximum temperature, humidity, and pressure may occur in different records.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to suggest that you do this using six queries, connected by `union all`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 'max temperature' as which, temperature as value, datetime
      FROM measurement
      WHERE nodeId = :nodeID AND datetime BETWEEN :datetimestart AND :datetimeend
      ORDER BY 2 DESC
      LIMIT 1
     ) t
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 'min temperature' as which, temperature as value, datetime
      FROM measurement
      WHERE nodeId =:nodeID AND datetime BETWEEN :datetimestart AND :datetimeend
      ORDER BY 2 ASC
      LIMIT 1
     ) t
UNION ALL
. . .
```

This is a bit more cumbersome, but you can return all the columns in the measurement table that you would like for each value.  So, you can get the humidity at the maximum temperature as well, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a  join with you result table and measurement

```
   $sqlmax = "
   select a.temperature, a.humidity, a.pressure, b.datetime 
   from (   SELECT 
        MAX(temperature) as temperature,
        MAX(humidity) as humidity,
        MAX(pressure) as pressure
        FROM measurement
        WHERE nodeId =:nodeId
        AND datetime BETWEEN :datetimestart 
        AND :datetimeend
  ) a inner join measurement as b on a.temperature = b.temperature 
              and a.humidity = b.humidity and a.pressure = b.pressure " ;
```